# Is a linear mixed model suitable for this experiment design?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, longitudinal-data-analysis

I would like to see if 1 year of musical training significantly changes the covariance between two independent variables (forward and backward digit span) and my dependent variables consisting of 4 speech perception conditions, measured within-subjects. Just to clarify, the variables in this study are as follows:

Time, 2 levels = T1 and T2;

Group, 2 levels = 1 (received musical training), 2 (controls);

DV, 4 levels: Speech-in-noise test with 4 different noise conditions;

IV 1: forward digit span;

IV 2: backward digit span

Please note, I do not want to use a factorial ANOVA in this case as I am not interested in mean differences or interactions, but only if musical training has significantly changed (i.e., increased/decreased) the covariation between the digit span scores and the speech in noise measures (individually or aggregated) at T2. I was wondering if anyone could confirm whether or not a linear mixed model would be the most suitable approach for this? And if so, I would be extremely grateful if you could highlight which are the fixed and which are the random effects.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think a mixed model may be appropriate? It is not obvious to me what grouping factor could be treated as random.

Comment: It is also not obvious to me what your dependent and independent variables are. Your research question seems to be about the correlation between two variables, yet you refer to these as independent variables. It would seem more appropriate to me to model the correlation between these as the dependant variable, with group, time and what you refer to as "DV" as fixed effects. The estimate for time would then be a measure of how the correlation changed between the time points. Can you provide more information about the digit span variables such as what they are and how they are measured?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The digit span variables are measures of working memory. The correlation of interest is between an aggregate of the speech-in-noise measures on the one hand, and the two digit span variables on the other. I would like to know if the covariance increases significantly more/less between T1 and T2 in one group than the other. Hope this makes more sense. I thought LMM might be appropriate for longitudinal data but I am not sure as this is my first longitudinal study. Do you think a different model would be more appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: How many subjects do you have ? Why do you not have a subject identifier variable?

Comment: There are 25 subjects in each group (experimental group and control group) and the subject identifier variable would be ID.

Comment: Ahh well that changes things completely. Its just that when you wrote *"the variables in this study are as follows:"* there was no mention of the subject identifier.

Comment: Apologies for the omission. I have calculated the groups' correlation coefficients at T1 and T2 and looked for signif./n.s. changes using software for comparing correlation coefficients, but it seems like a rough approach and I'm concerned it might be incorrect somehow for longitudinal analyses.

Comment: Indeed, you need to account for clustering. I will try to write an answer a little later.